# Copy/move requirements for the key/value types in a std::map?

Tags: c++, c++11

This code confuses me:

```
struct foo {
  int i;

  foo(int j) : i(j) {}

  foo(const foo &) = delete;
  foo(foo &&) = delete;
  foo &operator=(const foo&) = delete;
  foo &operator=(foo&&) = delete;
};

bool operator<(const foo &f1, const foo &f2)
{
  return f1.i < f2.i;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  std::map<foo,int> f;
  std::map<foo,int> f2 = f; //error (as expected)
  std::map<foo,int> f3 = std::move(f); //no error (why?)
  return 0;
}
```

Because I get no error there, it seems like when moving a map no key object is created (not even for moving another key object into it).

Why not? Can I rely on this behavior according to the C++11 standard?

More generally, what copying/moving requirements does a `std::map` place on the **key and value types** and under what conditions?

Comment: moving a map places _no_ requirements on the key and value.

Comment: @MooingDuck, that's not true if the allocator type doesn't propagate

Comment: ah right, allocators can mess with everything.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Copy-assignment of one map to another requires copying each item. Since you cannot copy items, you cannot copy-assign the maps.

Whether the actual map object is empty at runtime is immaterial, since these are purely *static* considerations, determined entirely by the *types* of the objects.

(It's like asking why `sin(0)` requires a floating point unit when clearly the result is an integer.)

Moving the entire map, on the other hand, is fine because the container is node-based and no actual values are mutated, just the nodes are. In fact, move-constructing or move-assigning node based containers doesn't require the elements to be copyable *or* movable *or* assignable at all.

(This should be true for all containers that manage dynamic memory in a suitable fashion, such as via `std::allocator<value_type>`, but it would of course not be true for something like `std::array`, and it would be interesting whether or not it would hold for `std::dynarray`, and as @Jonathan Wakely noted, if the allocation scheme isn't able to move nodes wholesale.)

Comment: Move-assigning a map of type `M` requires the element types to be `MoveInsertable` into `M` if `allocator_traits<M::allocator_type>::propagate_on_container_move_assignment::value` is false

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Oh dear. Yes, that's a very good point. It all depends on the allocator!

Comment: Damn damn damn allocators :-\

Comment: @JonathanWakely: The stateful and probagable and nestable new allocators frighten and distrub me. I can't claim to understand even the slightest part of them. I only saw that pages after pages of class synopses were added to accommodate them.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: (My inbox showed your original comment :-).)

Comment: The second half of my ACCU 2012 [C++11 Allocators](http://accu.org/content/conf2012/JonathanWakely-CXX11_allocators.pdf)  talk might help understand the changes ... but might not.  Re: original comment, yes, I toned it down ;-)

Comment: Do regular programmers have to worry about allocators?

Comment: In addition to JonathanWakely's good comments, note that the original code is actually not supposed to work in C++11, but will in C++1y because `propagate_on_container_move_assignment` is false for `std::allocator` in C++11, but true in C++1y.  This change was widely viewed as a silly defect in C++11, and implementors have aggressively made the change regardless of the client's requested standard conformance flags.

Comment: @JonathanWakely What was in your original comment?

Comment: I am not familiar with allocators. When do programmers really need to worry about them?

Comment: @roger.james, you don't need to worry about them except in quite specialized scenarios, e.g. using shared memory or very tight restrictions

Comment: @roger.james: I've heard from game designers who write for consoles that they like very particular control over dynamic allocations, since resources are tight and you're constantly pressed to get as close to, but never over, the edge. Custom allocators let you do that, so you can use the standard library and still meet your personal special needs.

Answer (score 3):

There's no error because only `map` moved, not elements of `map`. Just pointers to elements are assigned