# error by move assignment of map with non-copyable (but movable) key

Tags: c++, c++14, move-semantics, stdmap

Why does this doesn't work:

```
#include <memory>
#include <map>

std::map<std::unique_ptr<char>, std::unique_ptr<int>> foo();
std::map<std::unique_ptr<char>, std::unique_ptr<int>> barmap;

int main(){
  barmap=foo();
  return 0;
}
```

while this does:

```
#include <memory>
#include <map>

std::map<std::unique_ptr<char>, std::unique_ptr<int>> foo();
std::map<std::unique_ptr<char>, std::unique_ptr<int>> barmap;

int main(){

  std::map<std::unique_ptr<char>, std::unique_ptr<int>> tmp(foo());
  using std::swap;
  swap(barmap, tmp);
  return 0;
}
```

This has to do with the fact that key type in the map is not copyable (does std::map require that?). Relevant error lines when compiling with `g++ -std=c++14`:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.9/ext/new_allocator.h:120:4: error: use of deleted function ‘constexpr std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(std::pair<_T1, _T2>&&) [with _T1 = const std::unique_ptr<char>; _T2 = std::unique_ptr<int>]’
  { ::new((void *)__p) _Up(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
    ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_algobase.h:64:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/memory:62,
                 from pairMove.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_pair.h:128:17: note: ‘constexpr std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(std::pair<_T1, _T2>&&) [with _T1 = const std::unique_ptr<char>; _T2 = std::unique_ptr<int>]’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
       constexpr pair(pair&&) = default;
                 ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_pair.h:128:17: error: use of deleted function ‘std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with _Tp = char; _Dp = std::default_delete<char>]’
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/memory:81:0,
                 from pairMove.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/unique_ptr.h:356:7: note: declared here
       unique_ptr(const unique_ptr&) = delete;
```

Entire error message to be seen [at ideone](https://ideone.com/q8uIGB).

It seems to me that defaulted move constructor of `std::pair` attempts to use a copy constructor of `std::unique_ptr`. I presume that map assignment operator uses move assignments of new map contents over the old ones, and `std::swap` cannot do this since it needs to keep old contents intact, so it just swaps internal data pointers, so it avoids problems.

The necessity to (at least  be able to) move assign might come from [problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17603666/copy-move-requirements-for-the-key-value-types-in-a-stdmap) with `allocator_traits<M::allocator_type>::propagate_on_container_move_assignment` in C++11, but I was under impression that in C++14 the whole thing was fixed. I am not sure why STL would choose to move-assign elements instead of just exchanging data pointers between containers in move-assignment operator.

And all of the above doesn't explain why move-assignment of pairs contained in moved map fails - IMHO it shouldn't.

Btw: `g++ -v`:

```
gcc version 4.9.2 (Ubuntu 4.9.2-0ubuntu1~14.04)
```

Comment: Um, I think you have things switched around.  You say the second code block works but then you go on to show compiler errors for it.  Also there is no `tmp` in the first code block.  There is also no `MyPtr` defined in the second example.

Comment: @NathanOliver Sorry, my bad. both codes actually had errors - fixed now. The error at ideone.com is actually from a slightly different - but equivalent to the first block - code.

Comment: Both codes obviously fail to compile because foo is not defined, but if I even go this far to try to link it, then my problem will be solved already. I omitted `foo` definition because I didn't want to give compiler opportunity to optimize too much out and remove the problem.

Comment: I read through 23.2.1 in C++14 and it looks to me if the first code should work,   but this is quite a complicated section so maybe I am overlooking something

Comment: @M.M you're overlooking the fact that the value type is a pair<const Key, Value>. When you take an r-value reference of it, you can move the value but not the key - unless the key provides Key(const Key&&) - which unique_ptr does not.

Comment: The code has rvalue references of maps, not pairs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is a <s>bug</s> quality of implementation issue in libstdc++. If we look in the container requirements table (now [table 100](http://eel.is/c++draft/container.requirements#tab:containers.container.requirements)), one of the requirements is:

```
a = rv
```

where `a` is a value of type `X` (the container class) and `rv` denotes a non-const rvalue of type `X`. The operational semantics are described as:

> All existing elements of `a` are either move assigned to or destroyed

It is stated in [[map.overview]](http://eel.is/c++draft/map#map.overview-2) that:

> A `map` satisfies all of the requirements of a container

One of those requirements is move assignment. Now apparently libstdc++'s approach is to move assign elements even in the case where `Key` is non-copyable (which would make `pair<const Key, T>` non-moveable - note that it's only `Key`'s noncopyability that is relevant here). But there is no mandate that move assignment happens, it is merely an option. Note that the code compiles fine with libc++.

Comment: from table 100 in your link, on the row of the table that introduces a = rv, it says the semantics are "All existing elements of a are either move assigned to or destroyed". You can't move-assign a pair<const K, V> unless K has a move-assignment operator that takes a const K&& on the right hand side. I think libstc++ is conforming, libc++ is reaching beyond a pedantic interpretation of the phrase in the standard. My view is that the standard's wording is in error. It probably ought to say "will be destroyed if not move-assignable, otherwise *may* be move-assigned to".

Comment: @RichardHodges That interpretation would imply that associative containers are never move-constructible or move-assignable. I don't believe that the element moving requirement literally requires moving `value_type`s.

Comment: not so, because when the key is copyable (as they almost always are), the const K&& can bind to the const K& of the copy constructor.

Comment: I'm not saying that the implementations actually do this, but the requirement is allowed to be there, because the standard (IMHO wrongly) mandates it.

Comment: @RichardHodges I don't see that the standard mandates move-assignment. The existing elements could all just be destroyed and then the new tree grabbed from `rv`.

Comment: I completely agree that this would be the most obvious implementation. But the standard doesn't say that. It says, "either move-assigned to or destroyed". It implies (at least to me) that the implementation may do either.

Comment: I feel this really is quality of implementation - standard mandates either move-assignment or destruction. In this case, where key is not assignable at all (neither copy nor move), it seems that libstdc++ is not against the standard, but it could also detect this situation fairly easy and choose a second option - at least I don't see a reason not to. It should be effectively equivalent to my second code snippet, which works as expected.

Comment: @j_kubik Yeah that's why I crossed off bug. QoI seems right. Though I wonder about why move assigning is even a reasonable thing to do?

Comment: @Barry thinking about it, is move-assigning reasonable when the two containers have distinct allocators which are not managing a common resource? e.g. "allocator_-
traits<allocator_type>
::propagate_on_container_-
move_assignment::value is
false". In that case, the value_type pairs would need to be moved from one container to the other individually, otherwise the destination map would contain nodes created by the wrong instance of the allocator.

Comment: No, libstdc++'s problem is that it simply failed to do tag dispatch (or something equivalent), so the not-taken branch is still being compiled.

Comment: @T.C. So yes, bug?

Answer (score 5):

To me this looks like a fundamental failure of the specification in the C++ standard.  The specification goes too far in "do not repeat yourself", as to become unreadable and ambiguous (imho).

If you read further to the table **Allocator-aware container requirements** this same row says (for `a = rv`):

> *Requires:* If `allocator_traits<allocator_type>::propagate_on_container_move_assignment::value` is `false`, `T` is `MoveInsertable` into `X` and `MoveAssignable`. All existing elements of `a` are either move assigned to or destroyed. post: `a` shall be equal to the value that `rv` had before this assignment.

I think everyone can agree that `std::map<std::unique_ptr<char>, std::unique_ptr<int>>` is an allocator-aware container.  Then the question becomes:  What are the requirements on its move assignment operator?

If we look only at the *Allocator-aware container requirements*, then `MoveInsertable` and `MoveAssignable` are only required if `allocator_traits<allocator_type>::propagate_on_container_move_assignment::value` is `false`.  And this is a weaker requirement than stated by the *Container requirements* table which states that **all** elements must be `MoveAssignable` regardless of the properties of the allocator.  So must allocator-aware containers also meet the stricter requirements of containers?

Let's unwind this to what the standard *should* say if it wasn't trying so hard to not repeat itself.

*What does the implementation require?*

If `allocator_traits<allocator_type>::propagate_on_container_move_assignment::value` is `true` then all ownership of memory resources can be transferred from the rhs to the lhs during move assignment.  This means that `map` move assignment can do nothing but O(1) pointer twiddling to accomplish move assignment (when memory ownership can be transferred).  Pointer twiddling does not require any operations on the objects that the pointers point to.

Here is the libc++ implementation of `map` assignment when `allocator_traits<allocator_type>::propagate_on_container_move_assignment::value` is `true`:

https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/__tree#L1531-L1551

One can see that *absolutely no requirements* need to be placed on the `key_type` or `value_type`.

Should we artificially place requirements on these types?

What purpose would that serve?  Would it help or hurt clients of `std::map`?

My personal opinion is that making requirements on client types that aren't needed will only serve to frustrate the clients.

I also believe that the current style of specification of the C++ standard is so convoluted that even experts can't agree on what the specification says.  This isn't because the experts are idiots.  It is because making a correct, unambiguous specification (on this scale) is truly a very difficult problem.

Finally I believe that the intent is (or should be) that the Allocator-aware container requirements supersede the Container requirements when a specification conflict arises.

One final complication:  In C++11:

```
allocator_traits<allocator<T>>::propagate_on_container_move_assignment{} is false_type
```

where as in C++14:

```
allocator_traits<allocator<T>>::propagate_on_container_move_assignment{} is true_type
```

So the libstdc++ behavior is conforming in C++11, and the libc++ behavior is conforming in C++14.  [LWG issue 2103](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-defects.html#2103) made this change.

Answer (score 1):

```
barmap=foo();
```

is allowed to require a move-assignment into the map's `value_type`.

Reasoning:

from §23.4.4.1

> For a `map<Key,T>` the key_type is Key and the value_type is pair<**const
>   Key**,T>.

§ 23.2.3

> 5 For set and multiset the value type is the same as the key type. For map and multimap it is equal to `pair<const Key, T>`.
>
> 7 The associative containers meet all the requirements of Allocator-aware containers (23.2.1), except that
>   for map and multimap, the requirements placed on value_type in Table 95 apply instead to key_type
>   and mapped_type. [ Note: For example, in some cases key_type and mapped_type are required to be
>   CopyAssignable even though the associated value_type, pair, is not
>   CopyAssignable. — end note ]

From Table 95:

> Expression :
>
> a = rv
>
> Return type :
>
> X&
>
> Operational semantics:
>
> **All existing elements of a are either move assigned to** or destroyed
>
> Assertion/note pre-/post-condition:
>
> a shall be equal to the value that rv had before this assignment
>
> Complexity:
>
> linear

so you would need to provide a const Key&& move-assignment to make it portable.

like this:

```
#include <memory>
#include <map>

struct key {

  key(key&&);
  key(const key&&);
  key& operator=(key&&);
  key& operator=(const key&&);
};
bool operator<(const key& l, const key& r);

struct value {

};

using map_type = std::map<key, value>;

map_type foo();
map_type foo2();

int main(){
  auto barmap=foo();
  barmap = foo2();
  return 0;
}
```

see it compile here: https://godbolt.org/g/XAQxjt

link to 2015 draft standard I have used (I know there is a later one, but the line remains in the most recent draft, now in table 100)

http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2015/n4527.pdf

My apologies to anyone who finds the answer unacceptable, but the words really are there.

Comment: How is this copy assignment? Value produced from `foo` is an rvalue so it should use move-assignment. Using auto causes this to be move-construction - I know that it works, but what I need is move assignment.

Comment: It's a copy/move context.  `foo()` is a prvalue , so it is in fact move assignment

Comment: @j_kubik i've updated the answer in case I was not clear enough.

Comment: @M.M except that there is no move-assignment or move constructor for `const unique_ptr<>&&`... see updated answer.

Comment: @RichardHodges why does it work with a move-constructor ?

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki interesting question. looks like the move constructor moves the whole map, whereas the move-assignment logic is expressed in terms of move-assigning value_types. will have to investigate further.

Comment: @RichardHodges libc++ makes no problem with a move-assignment

Comment: Your answer makes some sense but Table 99 seems to specify that it should work anyway (case `a = rv`), IDK

Comment: @M.M i disagree. see the text in bold, quoted from table 95

Comment: @RichardHodges  The text you quoted does not appear in Table 95 in C++14 (N4140).  I am referring to Table 99 in N4140.  It would be good to include which document you refer to , when quoting the standard

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki While you are correct, the standard seems to indicate that it need not work

Comment: @M.M Table 99 is for **SequenceContainer**. Table 95 is for **AssociativeContainer**, of which std::map<> is one. Could this be where the confusion lies?
http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2015/n4527.pdf

Comment: @RichardHodges N4527 is not "the standard"

Comment: Is your argument that `pair<const K, V>` cannot satisfy "All existing elements of a are either move assigned to" because the key is const (and doesn't have a move-assignment operator taking const reference) ? If so, explain how it works with `K` as `std::string` - a `const string` cannot be move-assigned to either

Comment: @M.M correct. with 23.2.3 asserting that the value_type (and therefore type of element) is indeed a pair<const K, V> which would mean that for the element to be move-assigned to , operator=K(const K&&) would need to exist, or be allowed to decay to operator=(const K&)

Comment: @M.M in fairness, I think the OP has discovered a defect in the standard.

Comment: @M.M std::string is copy-assignable. In the absence of operator=(K const&&), operator=(K const&) may be selected instead. Remember that it is the pair being move-assigned, not the key. and move-assigned simply means that an r-value is presented on the right hand side. It does not mean that the pair must honour the request by actually moving. a copy is permissible.

Comment: Your own citation says " for map and multimap, the requirements placed on value_type in Table 95 apply instead to key_type and mapped_type" and therefore "All existing elements of a are either move assigned to or destroyed" applies not to `pair<const Key, T>` but to `Key` and `T` only.

Comment: Secondly, even if above were not true, standard requires either assignment or destruction. Implementation could possibly detect case where assignment is not possible and move entire data structure from one map to another without assigning separate objects at all - as in my second snippet with `std::swap`. I can't see why it is not possible - I agree with Barry, that it might be considered quality-of-implementation issue on libstdc++ part.

Comment: @j_kubik it's certainly counter-intuitive in libstdc++, and in my view there is unfortunate wording in the standard. To address your previous comment, applying  "All existing elements of a are either move assigned to or destroyed...  applies not to pair<const Key, T> ...but to Key..." would certainly imply to me that the standard is saying that the key must be move-assignable. Even though we agree that for the a=rv case, this seems illogical.

Comment: And as for `key(const key&&)`; I suppose that knowing that I will only assign empty containers (so no key will ever actually use this code) this might work, but I am not sure if using something like that is really in spirit of C++ . I cannot imagine sensible implementation of such constructor for a class like `std::unique_ptr` and even if I could, I cannot change `std::uniquie_ptr` definition, can I?

Comment: @j_kubik no you cannot. What you can do is wrap your unique_ptr into your own key type which supports copying (even if you never actually copy it), or make the key a [possibly wrapped] shared_ptr... or are you able to simplify the key type, and not use a pointer at all?

Comment: I could wrap unique_ptr into my own type - in fact I already do in my code, but defining a copy constructor (or const-move) is out of the question because this class is heavily used in my code and I really would like to get an error if I accidentally copy it. Defining such never-to-be-used methods just to cheat compiler in one place is a good way to mess up the rest of your code. For now, I use code from second snippet and it works; my question was rather about the principle.

Comment: Re. the comment ending "a copy is permissible", how do you copy into an existing `pair<const string, T>` though? Const objects cannot be copied to.

Comment: @M.M I guess you'd have to copy construct a new key while move-constructing a new value when building the new pair

Comment: You're assigning to an existing one though, not building a new one

Comment: @M.M that's a good point. I have raised this issue in the iso c++ mailing list looking for clarification as to whether it's a defect in the standard or whether there is something fundamental I am missing.